# Swift - handling Subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am having problems with `subviews`. Right now I have a `ViewController` and a `containerView`. The problem is that my `containerView` is on top of my `ViewControlller` so i can't click on the `button` inside my `ViewController`.

ViewController:

[image]

***Update***

[image]

Comment: Try setting `isModalInPresentation` of the container view controller to false.

Comment: not working sorry

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on here without any code. Have you tried Xcode's View Debugger?

Comment: no but tbh, there is not much code to it. I created the `containerView` in `Storyboard` and its a full size view, the same as my main `ViewController`

Comment: the `containerView` should be on top of my `ViewController`. I just need to be able to click the `button` which in my case is a `cell`

Comment: Add a screenshot of your storyboard hierarchy

Comment: @Koen any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by setting a height constraint for the "bottom-bar" and for the "settings"-button I added a 2nd `ContainerView`. Brute force but it works :)